# Ways to pass few huge arrays to an Fortran executable as command line arguments

Tags: arrays, fortran, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, intel-fortran

I am trying to run my program from a parent program by getting a few big arrays (~ 5 to 6 real*8 arrays of size 15 Million) as inputs and using the function `execute_command_line()` in Fortran. Making my program a subroutine to the parent program is not an option as my program is MPI based while the parent program is purely sequential and cannot be ported to MPI for now.

I tried writing the arrays as binary files and reading them in my program but I am facing serious memory constraints and performance hits. I am looking for other options and was wondering if passing arrays as command line arguments is an option for such huge arrays and if so how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: I'm going to guess that you've not seen what happens when you create a command line with a couple of thousand characters, let alone the billion or so that you'd be using here.

Comment: @francescalus What happens?

Comment: Even if you could do it why do you think passing these arrays as command line arguments would avoid the "serious memory constraints and performance hits" you are currently experiencing? If you have to read in and store the things, how can they being on the command line avoid this?

Comment: Your OS/shell will have limits on command line lengths, but even assuming they are large enough, we can expand on Ian Bush's comment. You have an array in the first program, which is copied to create the string to `execute_command_line`, which is copied by the shell, which is copied by the OS, which is copied by the second program in the destination array.  That's some overhead.

Comment: So the best method is just file io?

Comment: Yes            ...Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: One of the MPI ranks could open a named pipe and stream data to the sequential program.

Comment: @sidarthnarayanan what about a named pipe ?

Answer (score 0):

If your program is running on Linux, try to use a named pipe to avoid IO.